# Reply to comment YouTube style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a similar comments system to YouTube. What would be the easiest way of making a reply `textarea` appear under a comment when the button is clicked? I assume duplicating the `textarea` and making it `display:none` for each comment is not necessary.

**With textarea**

```
<div class="comment">
  <p>Bla bla</p>
  <a hred="" id="reply">Reply</a>
  <textarea class="reply"></textarea>   
</div>
```

**Without textarea**

```
<div class="comment">
  <p>Bla bla2</p>
  <a hred="" id="reply">Reply</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#reply').click(function(){

}
```

Comment: meh. in the time it took me to type the answer, two other people had already posted near identical answers.

Comment: @Spudley that just says that the question was to easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
$('#reply').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().append($('<textarea>').attr('class','reply'));
});
```

should do the job.

Comment: Just add-on to this answer. Click function needs to close. Replace `}` to `});`

Comment: @SivaCharan Thanks for notifying me. Fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on @user1419007 answer.

It already tests if you already have an textarea under the comment. If this is the case it will be *send*.

```
$('.reply').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().find('textarea').length < 1) {
        $(this).parent().append($('<textarea>').attr('class','reply'));
    } else {
        alert('Sending: ' + $(this).parent().find('textarea').val());
    }
});​
```

Here is an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7XaN/)

Answer (score 2):

IDs are supposed to be unique, so you shouldn't have multiple `#reply`s. Instead, you may add a class to each.

```
<div class="comment">
  <p>Bla bla</p>
  <a hred="" class="reply-button">Reply</a>
</div>
```

```js
$('.reply-button').click(function(){
  $(this).after($('<textarea>').attr('class','reply-box'));
});
```

Comment: Just add-on to this answer. Click function needs to close. Replace `}` to `});`